Problem with black holes on images after applying color blindness simulation in C# and ASM
I’m working on a university project where I’m trying to implement an algorithm that simulates different types of color blindness (Deuteranopia, Protanopia, Tritanopia) on images. The goal is to convert RGB color images (24 bpp) to simulate how they would appear to individuals with different types of color blindness.
Unfortunately, after applying the transformations for Protanopia and Deuteranopia, the resulting images show black holes. The image appears nearly black with some odd distortions that resemble "holes." I suspect that something might be wrong with the RGB channel transformations or scaling, but I can’t pinpoint the exact issue.
Problem description:
I’m using C# to handle the image processing and file I/O.
I’ve written assembly code (ASM) to simulate the color blindness transformations.
After running the simulation, the processed image is almost entirely black with strange "hole-like" areas.
What I’ve tried:
Double-checked the transformations for each color blindness type (Deuteranopia, Protanopia).
Ensured that the RGB values are correctly calculated and clamped within the 0-255 range.
Verified that the image is loaded and saved correctly in C#.
c# code:
    private void ProcessColorBlindnessAsm(int blindnessType)
{
    if (_originalImage == null || _processedImage == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Błąd: Image not loaded.");
        return;
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, _originalImage.Width, _originalImage.Height);
    BitmapData originalData = _originalImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    BitmapData processedData = _processedImage.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    int pixelCount = _originalImage.Width * _originalImage.Height;
    int stride = originalData.Stride;

    IntPtr originalPtr = originalData.Scan0;
    IntPtr processedPtr = processedData.Scan0;

    try
    {
        Parallel.For(0, Environment.ProcessorCount, partition =>
        {
            int rowsPerPartition = _originalImage.Height / Environment.ProcessorCount;
            int startRow = partition * rowsPerPartition;
            int endRow = (partition == Environment.ProcessorCount - 1) ? _originalImage.Height : startRow + rowsPerPartition;

            int partitionPixelCount = (endRow - startRow) * _originalImage.Width;
            IntPtr originalPartitionPtr = IntPtr.Add(originalPtr, startRow * stride);
            IntPtr processedPartitionPtr = IntPtr.Add(processedPtr, startRow * stride);

            // Pass blindnessType to the ASM function
            DeuteranopiaAsm(originalPartitionPtr, processedPartitionPtr, partitionPixelCount, stride, blindnessType);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Error while proccesing asm: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        _originalImage.UnlockBits(originalData);
        _processedImage.UnlockBits(processedData);
    }
}

asm code:
    .code
DeuteranopiaAsm proc

SimulateColorBlindnessASM:
    ; RCX = originalImage (pointer)
    ; RDX = processedImage (pointer)
    ; R8  = pixelCount (number of pixels)
    ; R9  = stride (bytes per row)
    ; R10 = blindnessType (0 = Deuteranopia, 1 = Protanopia, 2 = Tritanopia)

    mov r11, rcx              ; Save pointer to original image
    mov r12, rdx              ; Save pointer to processed image

    xor rbx, rbx              ; Use RBX as pixel counter

PixelLoop:
    cmp rbx, r8               ; Check if all pixels are processed
    jge EndLoop               ; If rbx >= pixelCount, exit

    mov rax, rbx              ; Copy pixel counter to rax
    shl rax, 1                ; rax = rbx * 2 (shift left by 1)
    add rax, rbx              ; rax = rax + rbx = rbx * 3

    ; Load color data (B, G, R)
    mov al, byte ptr [r11 + rax]     ; Load blue channel
    mov cl, byte ptr [r11 + rax + 1] ; Load green channel
    mov dl, byte ptr [r11 + rax + 2] ; Load red channel

    ; Select transformation based on blindnessType
    cmp r10, 0               ; Check if Deuteranopia
    je SimulateDeuteranopia
    cmp r10, 1               ; Check if Protanopia
    je SimulateProtanopia
    cmp r10, 2               ; Check if Tritanopia
    je SimulateTritanopia
    jmp EndPixel             ; Skip if invalid type

SimulateDeuteranopia:
    ; Transform for Deuteranopia
    movzx r8d, dl              ; Convert red channel to 32-bit
    imul r8d, 625              ; R = R * 0.625
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 375              ; G = G * 0.375
    add r8d, r9d               ; New Red = (R * 0.625 + G * 0.375)
    shr r8d, 8                 ; Divide by 256 to fit in byte range
    
     ; Green transformation (G = G * 0.7)
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 700              ; G = G * 0.7
    shr r9d, 10                ; Divide by 1024 to fit in byte range

    ; Blue transformation (B = B * 0.8)
    movzx r10d, al             ; Convert blue channel to 32-bit
    imul r10d, 800             ; B = B * 0.8
    shr r10d, 10               ; Divide by 1024 to fit in byte range

    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel

    jmp EndPixel

SimulateProtanopia:
    ; Transform for Protanopia
    movzx r8d, dl              ; Convert red channel to 32-bit
    imul r8d, 567              ; R = R * 0.567
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 433              ; G = G * 0.433
    add r8d, r9d               ; New Red = (R * 0.567 + G * 0.433)
    shr r8d, 8                 ; Divide by 256
    
     ; Green transformation (G = G * 0.558)
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 558              ; G = G * 0.558
    shr r9d, 10                ; Divide by 1024 to fit in byte range

    ; Blue transformation (B = B * 0.0)
    xor r10d, r10d             ; Set blue channel to 0

    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel

    jmp EndPixel

SimulateTritanopia:
    ; Transform for Tritanopia
    movzx r8d, dl              ; Convert red channel to 32-bit
    imul r8d, 950              ; R = R * 0.95
    movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 433              ; G = G * 0.433
    add r8d, r9d               ; New Red = (R * 0.95 + G * 0.433)
    shr r8d, 8                 ; Divide by 256
   
   movzx r9d, cl              ; Convert green channel to 32-bit
    imul r9d, 433              ; G = G * 0.433
    shr r9d, 10                ; Divide by 1024 to fit in byte range

    ; Blue transformation (B = B * 0.567)
    movzx r10d, al             ; Convert blue channel to 32-bit
    imul r10d, 567             ; B = B * 0.567
    shr r10d, 10               ; Divide by 1024 to fit in byte range

    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel

    jmp EndPixel

EndPixel:
    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel

    inc rbx                   ; Increment pixel counter
    jmp PixelLoop             ; Repeat for next pixel

EndLoop:
    ret
DeuteranopiaAsm endp
end

Can you help me?
original image:

how it should look like:

my asm output:


For starters, your asm code violates calling convention with regards to preserved registers. You are lucky you don't get a crash. Also it does not seem like you have any reason to use assembly.

You’re multiplying red and green by 1000 combined and then dividing by 256 to fit in 8 bits? That doesn’t make sense at least. In tritanoptia even worse, 1383. You also store pixels twice but that won’t cause this issue.

Is this a practice attempt before you use SSE, AVX, or AVX-512?  You can easily get a compiler to make asm that processes each byte separately with scalar integer instructions.  And C# has reasonable intrinsics for SIMD vectors, so normally you'd want to use that instead of hand-coding in asm.

You can use C# to manipulate pixel buffers; you don't need ASM. And since you have  the source and the desired image, I would "interpolate" between the two to arrive at a "transformation" (formula). But that only works for those colors. (RGB progressions are not intuitive, in my experience)

I wonder if you read my answer to your previous question about this program!
You are repeating the same mistakes all over again.
Just to name three:

; R10 = blindnessType (0 = Deuteranopia, 1 = Protanopia, 2 = Tritanopia)


The 5th argument is passed on the stack (above the 32-byte shadow space).
At the top of the PixelLoop you check this R10 register that supposedly contains the blindnessType, but every single Blue transformation later changes the R10D register. You immediately lose that blindnessType information. Remember that R10D is not a separate register at all, but rather the lowest 32 bits of the 64-bit register R10.

mov rax, rbx              ; Copy pixel counter to rax
shl rax, 1                ; rax = rbx * 2 (shift left by 1)
add rax, rbx              ; rax = rax + rbx = rbx * 3


My version of the code showed you a much better way to address the RGB bytes, not requiring this ugly * 3 calculation.

mov al, byte ptr [r11 + rax]     ; Load blue channel


You can't use AL to hold the blue channel and at the same time use RAX as on offset in the pixeldata. AL is the lowest byte of the RAX register. AL is not a separate register.

All of your fractional calculations are wildly wrong. I explained that too in my previous answer (oktober 21) ...


; Blue transformation (B = B * 0.0)
xor r10d, r10d             ; Set blue channel to 0

; Store processed pixel back into the image
mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel


How can you miss this? If the Blue transformation is just zero, and you reset the R10D register, why then do you store AL and not R10B ? (Or just write mov byte [r12 + rax], 0).

EndPixel:
    ; Store processed pixel back into the image
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax], al     ; Store blue channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 1], cl ; Store green channel
    mov byte ptr [r12 + rax + 2], dl ; Store red channel


Cleanup required! Why does the code at EndPixel store the new data a second time ?
